# Defining a method inside a module in ruby (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, module

I'm learning ruby, I come up on something that I don't understand. I know that **modules** in ruby are used for namespacing with **::** (or .) and mixing with **include** directive.
The problem comes when I group some methods inside a module, without putting them inside a class.
Here's an example:

```
module Familiar
  #this will not work
    def ask_age
      return "How old are you?"
    end
  #this will work
    def Familiar::greeting
      return "What's up?"
    end
end
# this call returns **NoMethodError** 
puts(Familiar::ask_age()) 
# this call works fine
puts(Familiar::greeting())
```

Why do I need to include the namespace to define the method, I'm already inside the namespace **Familiar** why do I have to repeat my self and put **Familiar::greeting**
You can test my example online following this link: http://codepad.org/VUgCVPXN

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [Ruby documentation on Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-module_function) answers this in its introduction text.

This form:

```
module Familiar
  def ask_age
    return "How old are you?"
  end
end
```

defines `#ask_age` as an *instance* method on Familiar. However, you can't instantiate Modules, so you can't get to their instance methods directly; you mix them into other classes. Instance methods in modules are more or less unreachable directly.

This form, by comparison:

```
module Familiar
  def self.ask_age
    return "What's up?"
  end
end
```

defines `::ask_age` as a *module function*. It is directly callable, and does not appear on included classes when the module is mixed into another class.

Comment: Which means that the OP could perform `@familiar = Familiar.new`, `@familiar.ask_age`?

Comment: @RichPeck no, modules can't be instantiated. But this module can be included in class, instance of those could use `ask_age` method.

Comment: So the only way to call a method directly from a module is if it's either a "class" method, or the method is in a class? How would you call instance methods from a method?

Comment: @RichPeck, your inquiry is hard to understand. You can send any message to any object from anywhere, and therefore also call any method of any object from anywhere (provided that the object chooses to respond to your message).

Comment: In the second part of your answer, you say, "defines ::ask_age as a module function", but the example shows self.greeting. Is that an error?